# Не выполняются makemigrations и не создаются таблицы в БД Django

Tags: база-данных, django, visual-studio-2017, миграция, обработка-ошибок

Разработка в Visual Studio 2017.
При выполнении "makemigrations", а также при проверке "manage.py check" имею один и тот же ответ системы:

---

**Идет выполнение: manage.py makemigrations**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "...\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "...\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 328, in execute

return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: app_entry

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "...\DjangoWeb\manage.py", line 17, in <module>

execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

File "...\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()

File "...\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)

File "...\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)

File "...\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 327, in execute
    self.check()

File "...\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,

File "...\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)

File "...\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)

File "...\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)

File "...\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()

File "...\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 256, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:

File "...\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

File "...\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 407, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)

File "...\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

File "...\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 400, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)

File "...\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File ".\DjangoWeb\urls.py", line 8, in <module>
    import app.views

File ".\app\views.py", line 68, in <module>
    ENTRY_COUNT = Entry.objects.count() # кол-во зявок в БД

File "...\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "...\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 364, in count
    return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)

File "...\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 499, in get_count
    number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']

File "...\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 480, in get_aggregation
    result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)

File "...\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 899, in execute_sql
    raise original_exception

File "...\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 889, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "...\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "...\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "...\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File ...\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "...\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "...\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 328, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: app_entry
```

---

При этом удалены все файлы миграций в папке проекта "migration", кроме файла "--init--.py", и удалён файл самой БД и вновь создан системой, но постоянно выдает вышеприведенную ошибку..

В чем тут может быть дело и как это поправить?

Comment: Это точно полный traceback?

Comment: Добавил полный Traceback..

Comment: Как так получилось, что у вас выполняется строка `ENTRY_COUNT = Entry.objects.count()` в вашем `views.py`? Вы зачем-то обращаетесь к базе за пределами вьюхи?

Comment: Точно, так и есть. Глобальная переменная ENTRY_COUNT создана с целью получить количество всех экземпляров из БД, чтобы использовать её значение в нескольких вьюхах...

Comment: Ну в общем так нельзя делать, уберите это куда-нибудь

Comment: Убрал обращение в БД во вьюху. Всё заработало.. Почему нельзя обратиться к БД вне функций представления?

Comment: Потому что модули проекта загружаются ещё до того, как БД будет создана

Comment: Ясно. Благодарю за оперативную консультацию! )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы добавить в вашу существующую базу данных необходимую таблицу(у меня это была account_profile), необходимо для начала скачать «DB Browser for SQLite» и проделать следующее:

1. Скопируйте уже имеющуюся ‘db.sqlite3’ в какую-нибудь папку.
2. Удалите ее из папки с проектом.
3. Запустите «python3 manage.py make migrations’», затем «python3 manage.py migrate».
4. Откройте вашу новую базу данных в «DB Browser for SQLite».
5. Затем вам необходимо экспортировать ‘account_profile’-таблицу как CSV файл. Показано в image1(снизу комментария)
6. Затем удалите вашу новую ДБ и закиньте обратно старую
7. Откройте теперь вашу старую ДБ в  «DB Browser for SQLite», нажмите «Файл»—>«Импорт»—>«Таблицу как файл CSV» и выберите ваш CSV файл(как раз в нем и содержится необходимая таблица)
8. Затем вы увидите, что в таблице столбцы называются как ‘field1’ и  ‘field2’, переменяйте их в ‘id’ ’user_id’ соответственно. Показано на image2 и image3
9. Затем можно либо удалить в базе данных админа, либо посмотреть, какой у него id и вписать(например у админа id-5, пишем в столбец ‘id’ - ‘1’, в столбец ‘user_id’ - ‘5’)

Если возникнут какие-то проблемы, пишите, с радостью отвечу)

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

[image: Результат)]

Comment: Вы дали один и тот же ответ в трёх темах за короткое время. Вы уверены, что этот ответ  с точностью отвечает на вопрос в каждом топике?

Comment: Да, просто нужно будет добавлять таблицу не такую, которая требовалась у меня, а, например, в этом топике app_entry

Comment: Хмм, на англ. SO на вопрос, зачем повторять ответ в разных топиках, вы ответили, что вы новенький и не знакомы с правилами. Там тоже были только разные таблицы?

Comment: Там посмотрел проблему у людей, у них были тоже проблемы с тем, что нет таблицы какой-либо.
Впредь буду только под одним топиком оставлять комментарий.
Прогулял сутки и не нашел ответа, подумал, будет полезно всем это решение, а не просто: "Удалите БД свою и делайте миграцию, теряя все данные".